# how would you remove the blank entry from array

Tags: c#

How would you remove the blank item from the array?

Iterate and assign non-blank items to new array?

```
String test = "John, Jane";

//Without using the test.Replace(" ", "");

String[] toList = test.Split(',', ' ', ';');
```

Comment: Thanks for so many perspectives, love it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the overload of `string.Split` that takes a `StringSplitOptions`:

```
String[] toList = test.Split(new []{',', ' ', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Gotta love SO - never knew about `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` :)

Comment: @rod Glad to be of help. I'll leave it up to you to implement caching of the delimiter array if you are going to call this repeatedly.

Comment: @Oded I second that. +1, @chibacity, for teaching me something this afternoon.

Answer (score 5):

You would use [the overload of `string.Split` which allows the suppression of empty items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx):

```
String test = "John, Jane";
String[] toList = test.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ', ';' }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Or even better, you wouldn't create a new array each time:

```
 private static readonly char[] Delimiters = { ',', ' ', ';' };
 // Alternatively, if you find it more readable...
 // private static readonly char[] Delimiters = ", ;".ToCharArray();

 ...

 String[] toList = test.Split(Delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

`Split` doesn't modify the list, so that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] result = toList.Where(c => c != ' ').ToArray();
```

Comment: var result = toList.Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)).ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

Try this out using a little LINQ:

```
var n = Array.FindAll(test, str => str.Trim() != string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in a list then call the toArray method of the list, or with LINQ you could probably just select the non blank and do toArray.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] toList = test.Split(',', ' ', ';').Where(v => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(v.Trim())).ToArray();
```

Comment: `' '` will still cause `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to return false. If you want to use `IsNullOrEmpty`, you'd have to `Trim()` it first.

Answer (score 0):

If the separator is followed by a space, you can just include it in the separator:

```
String[] toList = test.Split(
  new string[] { ", ", "; " },
  StringSplitOptions.None
);
```

If the separator also occurs without the trailing space, you can include those too:

```
String[] toList = test.Split(
  new string[] { ", ", "; ", ",", ";" },
  StringSplitOptions.None
);
```

Note: If the string contains truely empty items, they will be preserved. I.e. `"Dirk, , Arthur"` will not give the same result as `"Dirk, Arthur"`.